# Batch processing many files

Tags: shell-script, command-line

I have many separate lists from all of which lines containing "@" as the start are wanted. I am now using `sh list_of_commands` to process the files. I am wondering if there is a smarter method to do the job.

1) How could I batch process all the files without writing all the command lines one by one?

2) Any method that names the output files by adding a suffix to the names of input files?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why the reference to [batch](https://linux.die.net/man/1/batch)? Did you read about shell scripting?

Comment: are you asking how to extract lines that start with `@`? Or combine them into a single input? Is `list_of_commands` the name of a script, or a sequence of commands?  #2 (suffixes) might be a separate question, but needs clarification on how to generate those suffixes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script crawls through all the files in the directory in which the script is executed and applies commands to it one by one. Is that the thing you want?

```
#! /bin/sh
for file in *
do
   if [[ -f "$file"  ]]; then
      # process the file with name in "$file" here
   fi
done
```

You can perform the renaming of a file as requested by using the following statement inside the above loop:

```
mv "$file"  "$(echo" $file" | sed -n "s|^\(.*\)\(\.[0-9a-zA-Z]*\)$|\1_su\2|p")"
```

It places the suffix "_su" in front of the file extension suffix but at the end of the filename. If the files have no extension then it places the suffix at the end of the filename.

Comment: Note that the `echo" $file"` in the command substitution is an issue that would give you an error. Also, you artificially limit the filenames that this works on by saying that filename suffixes may only contain alphanumeric characters. Your `sed` also does not add a suffix to files without a dot in their names.

Answer (score 1):

1. Collect the commands in a script (see below)
2. Append a suffix to the filename given on the command line of the script and use that as the output filename.

```
#!/bin/sh

for name in "$@"; do
    some_utility "$name" >"$name.suffix"
done
```

`"$@"` will expand to the quoted list of things that you have on the command line.  For example, with

```
$ ./script.sh a b "hello world" 123
```

The variable `$name` will get the values `a`, `b`, `hello world` and `123` on consecutive iterations of the loop.  You would pass your input files in this manner, or like

```
$ ./script.sh input*.txt
```

which would give it all files matching the given pattern in the current directory.

The variable `$name` may then be used as the name of each input file and you may add a suffix to the name by simply tagging it onto the end of that value (and use that as the name for an output file, for example).

Replace the line inside the loop with something that does the actual processing of the file `$name`.

The script has to be made executable to be able to run with `./script.sh`. You do this with `chmod +x script.sh`.